# Center image inside anchor tag

Tags: html, css, anchor

Need to center image inside anchor tag.  Tried `margin: 0 auto;`. But not worked.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0yL3gna/).

I am using bootstrap and a custom css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Achieved with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.navbar-brand {
  text-align: center;
  display:    inline-table;
  position:   relative;
}
```

and if neccessary only remove the padding `<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 30px">` or make it `padding-bottom:0;`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0yL3gna/2/)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the  tag `display:block; width:100%`, and then set the image with `margin:0 auto`:

```
.navbar-brand {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
.navbar-brand img {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qeo88uwj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bootstrap class "navbar-brand"
and replace with the following class

https://jsfiddle.net/y0yL3gna/3/

```
   .class-name{
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
```

And html will be

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar bgcol col_org">
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 30px">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="class-name" href="#" target="_self"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/android-128.png" alt="flower"></a> 
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove float and set display:block for anchor tag and margin: 0 auto will work for img tag.

```
.navbar-brand {
   display:block;
}
.navbar-brand img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modified some html, with your style. Try this!

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.bgcol {
  /*background-color: #1d3179;*/
  background-color: #000000;
  border: #fff;
  color: fff
}

.bgcol .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.bgcol a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.col_org {
  background: #1d3179;
}

.col_org:hover {
  background: #1d3179;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar bgcol col_org">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 30px">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="" style=" width: 100%; display: block;" href="#" target="_self"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/android-128.png" style="margin: auto; display: block;" alt="flower"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```